# Flink's POJO serializer for an interface

Tags: java, apache-flink

Let's say we have this contrived example of an interface Shape and its implementations. How I can serialize `myPojo` (with the POJO serializer) which contains a shape? Both Circle and Rectangle are POJOs.

```
public interface Shape {
    public double area(); 
}

public class Circle implements Shape{
    // constructors
    // radius
    // implement area();
    // getters, setters
}

public class Rectangle implements Shape {
    // constructors
    // height, width
    // implement area();
    // getters, setters
}

public class MyPojo {
    int anotherField;
    Shape shape;
    // constructors
   // getters, setters
}
```

My execution config looks like this:

```
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.getConfig().disableGenericTypes();
    env.getConfig().registerPojoType(Shape.class);
    env.getConfig().registerPojoType(Circle.class);
    env.getConfig().registerPojoType(Rectangle.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Shape interface has no fields, even if creating a dummy field is considered static thus having the same result. The "hack" solution which I resulted in, is to provide an empty HashMap for the fields:

```java
public class ShapeTypeInfoFactory extends TypeInfoFactory<Shape> {
  @Override
  public TypeInformation<Shape> createTypeInfo(
      Type t, Map<String, TypeInformation<?>> genericParameters) {
    return Types.POJO(Shape.class, new HashMap<>());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shape don't have valid methods to be consider a [POJO](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/serialization/types_serialization/#pojos)

> All fields are either public or must be accessible through getter and setter functions. For a field called foo the getter and setter methods must be named getFoo() and setFoo().

```
public interface Shape {
    public double getArea(); 
    public void setArea(double area); 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).